# Guava string sorting

Tags: java, guava

I've got the following collection of values: ["LA", "INTL", "ca", null].

I need to sort them in alphabetical, case-insensitive order without throwing any possible NPE.

How to do this properly by using guava library?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can user the [`Ordering#nullsFirst()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#nullsFirst()) (or [`Ordering#nullsLast()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#nullsLast())) to take care of the `null` entries in your list.

[`Ordering`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) implements the [`java.util.Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html?is-external=true) interface so you can use it like:

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("LA", "INTL", "ca", null);
Ordering<String> ordering = Ordering.from(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).nullsFirst();
Collections.sort(myList, ordering);
```

Comment: I have never paid attention to the fact that an `Ordering` actually implemented `Comparator`! +1

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Ordering`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) class:

```
Ordering.from(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).nulls{First,Last}()
    .sortedCopy(yourList);
```

Comment: Does it sort in alphabetical order?

Comment: It sorts according to the `char` values and it happens that the values for letters are sorted the same way as `char`s, so the answer is yes ;)

Comment: [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER): “**Since:** 1.2”. Not the slightest connection to Java 8. But if you want to sort naturally human readable text, you may consider using [`Collator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html), Since 1.0…